# get selected value in controller - jsp/spring

Tags: spring, jsp

I am trying to pass value from  in jsp to POST controller.

i have the controller get:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/matches/{pageNumber}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String games( @PathVariable Integer pageNumber, Model model ) {


    ....



    //build map for dropdown compatitions
    HashMap<Integer, String> leaguesMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    leaguesMap.put(1, "Top Leagues");
    leaguesMap.put(2, "All");
    for (Competition competition : competitions) {
        if(!leaguesMap.containsKey(competition.getApiId())){
            leaguesMap.put(competition.getApiId(), competition.getName()); 
        }
    }






    model.addAttribute("leaguesMap", leaguesMap);
    .....
    return "upcomingMatches";
}
```

And then in jsp:

```
 <form:form  modelAttribute="leaguesMap" action="drop" class="dropdown-leagues" method="POST">
                                       <form:select path="${leaguesMap.value}"  id="league-selection"   onchange="this.form.submit()"   class="form-control select-filter select2-hidden-accessible"   aria-hidden="true"> 
                                            <form:options items="${leaguesMap}" />                                            
                                     </form:select>          
                                  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>             
                           </form:form>
```

I am trying to get the selected value in POST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/matches/{pageNumber}/drop", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String games( @ModelAttribute("leaguesMap")  String leaguesMap, @PathVariable Integer pageNumber, BindingResult result) {

    String fff = leaguesMap;
    System.out.println("asadasdadsa"+fff);

    return "redirect:/matches/{pageNumber}/";
}
```

But getting always null. 
If you can give me direction how to proceed , it will be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model class League.class

```
public class League {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Change your get controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/matches/{pageNumber}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String games( @PathVariable Integer pageNumber, Model model ) {
            ....

            //build map for dropdown compatitions
            HashMap<Integer, String> leaguesMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            leaguesMap.put(1, "Top Leagues");
            leaguesMap.put(2, "All");
            for (Competition competition : competitions) {
                if(!leaguesMap.containsKey(competition.getApiId())){
                    leaguesMap.put(competition.getApiId(), competition.getName());
                }
            }
            model.addAttribute("leaguesMap", leaguesMap);
            model.addAttribute("league", new League());

            .....


       return "upcomingMatches";
    }
```

Change your jsp:

```
<form:form  modelAttribute="league" action="drop" class="dropdown-leagues" method="POST">
    <form:select path="id"  id="league-selection"   onchange="this.form.submit()"   class="form-control select-filter select2-hidden-accessible"   aria-hidden="true">
        <form:options items="${leaguesMap}" />
    </form:select>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form:form>
```

And finally your post controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/matches/{pageNumber}/drop", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String games( @ModelAttribute("league") League league, @PathVariable Integer pageNumber, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("asadasdadsa" + league.getId());

    return "redirect:/matches/{pageNumber}/";
}
```

Comment: Does it make sense to have a model class for every dropdown?

Comment: You do not need to have model for every drop down, instead make model according to your form contents.

Comment: What if i need to get the value from jsp without form? is it possible?

Comment: You can send ajax request to your controller

Comment: "Required League parameter 'league' is not present " - i am getting this error. Tried to follow exactly what you showed me

Comment: Ok my problem was i use "@requestparam" instead of @ModelAttribute
Now it is resolved

Comment: i used @ModelAttribute but did not help. i think that the form is mandatory to get this.